# MonoGame develop3d branch not building on OS X

Tags: macos, mono, monogame

I've successfully built been using the stable branch of MonoGame and the MonoDevelop templates for a while, and now I want to upgrade to the develop3d branch to utilize all its features. But when I build it, it gives me the error:

```
~/MonoGame/MonoGame.Framework/GamerServices/GamerProfile.cs(67,24): warning CS0628: `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.GamerProfile.Dispose(bool)': new protected member declared in sealed class
~/MonoGame/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/GraphicsCapabilities.cs(47,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `OpenTK' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I'm totally lost on why this is happening. What OpenTK should I reference? Does it not come with it, so I'd have to download it or something?

EDIT: Building this in Terminal with `xbuild` and building it in MonoDevelop both yield the same result.

Comment: Monogame has a third party `libs` folder that is linked to a separate github repo. Did you download the files for `libs` repo? See this link for the `libs` folder https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop/ThirdParty

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution; replace this in the beginning of `Graphics/GraphicsCapabilities.cs`:

```
#if OPENGL
#if GLES
using OpenTK.Graphics.ES20;
//...
```

with:

```
#if MONOMAC
using MonoMac.OpenGL;
#elsif OPENGL
#if GLES
using OpenTK.Graphics.ES20;
//...
```